# Почему URP меняет цвета моделей?

Tags: unity3d

Вот как это выглядит, когда я переключаюсь на стандартный RP. Цвета моделей светлые.
[image: Встроенный RP]
Но когда я включаю URP, то при автоматическом переключении шейдеров, на всех моделях, имеющих собственные материалы, цвет становится намного темнее. Если менять шейдеры вручную, то все нормально, но у меня слишком много моделей, чтобы делать для каждого отдельный материал.
[image: Универсальный RP]
Как это исправить? Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: И переведите вопрос на русский язык. Если не можете - задайте его на англоязычном сайте сети Stack Exchange.